# searching/filtering on negative days and time in column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to filter/search on negative dates/times in a column. I already filtered the difference between dates, dropped NaN and create frame via:

```
df = (df['date1'] - df['date2']).dropna().to_frame(name=None)
```

**Result of dataset**

```
    0
0   8 days 00:00:00
1   8 days 00:00:00
2   43 days 00:00:00
3   -42 days 06:50:00
4   147 days 23:00:00
```

**I tried this:**

I tried using timedelta or searching on values but that did not work.

**Expected result**

```
    0
3   -42 days 06:50:00
```

Appreciate the help and effort. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter negative Timedeltas from subtracted Series:

```
s = df['date1'] - df['date2']

out = s[s < pd.Timedelta(0)].to_frame(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Filtering out the unwanted days beforehand can be more handy:

```
df = df.query('date1 > date2').eval('date1 - date2').dropna().to_frame(name=None)
```